# Pack and unpack a pair of integers to hex

Tags: ruby, pack, unpack

I have a pair of 32 bit integers in Little-Endian format and i have to transform in hexadecimal value and reverse the process.
I know how to transform to hexadecimal but i have problems to turn back to integer.

```
h = [15325,24748]

i = h.pack("S*").unpack('N*').first
 => 3711675488 

hex-value = i.to_s(16)
 => "dd3bac60"
```

Now, how can i transform "dd3bac60" back to [15325,24748] ?

Thanks

Comment: Note those look like they are being treated as 16-bit integers, not 32-bit. The end result is 32 bit number expressed in hex.

Answer (score 1):

Just do everything in reverse order, and invert your pack/unpack logic:

```
hex_string = "dd3bac60"
[hex_string.to_i(16)].pack('N*').unpack('S*')
  => [15325, 24748]
```

Explanation: Each function you apply in your forward transformation has an inverse, so just apply them in reverse order:

- `String#to_i( base )` is inverse of `Integer.to_s( base )`
- `Array#pack('N*')` is inverse of `String#unpack('N*')`
- `String#unpack('S*')` is inverse of `Array#pack('S*')`